# How to get widget from QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtabwidget

I'm writing a simple text editor and using QTabWidget in it. For some QActon from QMenu I need to work with some widget from QTabWidget. QTabWidget::widget() return QWidget, but I need QTextEdit, which I added to QTabWidget using addTab(). **How do I get a QTextEdit from QTabWidget**?

```
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
tabWidget->addTab(textEdit, "text_edit");

//How to get textEdit by index or somethin from tabWidget?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QWidget * QTabWidget::widget ( int index )` is the droid you are looking for ;)

Comment: But this method return QWidget and I need QTextEdit.

Comment: try `QTextEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(tabWidget->widget(index));`. this should fix dem problem